# Preloading Instantiated Class Objects inside a main Class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, preloader

I have a main class in which 3 other class objects are managed and instantiated and are all extended from Sprite. My issue is getting these loaded correctly as I have external assets(images,and sounds) being loaded into these 3 classes. I have a simple .fla that is referencing the "Main". How would I go about ensuring the appropriate class instance is being loaded properly before it is added to the stage?

I have tried making the three classes inherit from the Loader class to retrieve the bytesloaded/total for the class but this causes other issues in the code that require attributes from Sprite. Would I need to preload ALL assets inside the class first, thus making the instantiated object on "Main" preloaded? Thank you for any help/advice.

Comment: in Main.as when you declare that `public var myClassRefname : myClass = new myClass();` you pretty much running it there and then. Any code in that class's `public function myClass() { //etc }` including one that loads items will happen here before the next line back in Main.as. So you could also have those classes **[despatch a custom event](http://blog.cjgammon.com/as3-custom-events-made-easy/)** when they are finishing loading all their items. Main.as will listen for these and maybe update a counter so when `classes_loaded_count == 3; //assume all assets are loaded` and proceed as usual: }

Comment: Most likely Flash has done this for you already, especially if you refer those classes in `Main` by their names, as in `var a:ClassOne;`. In case your other classes are located in separate SWFs, then you can instantiate a `Loader` to load that SWF and then use `getDefinitionByName()` to get the class info out of the loader's content once the loader dispatches `Event.COMPLETE`. There are security issues you have to work around, but it's doable.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help. This particular application was being deployed in a learning management system. The issue was the application its self was freezing due to a .js script used for SCORM communication. However, it was very useful for me to learn how flash is managing instantiation, I really appreciate the help both of you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all very much for your help. This particular application was being deployed in a learning management system. The issue was the application its self was freezing due to a .js script used for SCORM communication. However, it was very useful for me to learn how flash is managing instantiation, I really appreciate the help both of you provided.